# Why does this regex method not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex

If you invoke the `test` method on a `RegExp`, does that somehow "complete" the `RegExp`. A subsequent exec invocation appears to no longer work.

```
var isoDateRegEx = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g;
var isoDateString = '2001-01-01';

if (!isoDateRegEx.test(isoDateString)) {
  throw 'isoDateString must be in ISO 8601 format.';
}

var captures = isoDateRegEx.exec(isoDateString); // null
```